# Postgres.app upgrade, now Rails app won't start

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.2, postgres.app

I just upgraded my Postgres.app to latest version (9.2.4.1) am now unable to start my Rails app using Foreman or Rails server.

`` /Users/memoht/Sites/myapp/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/memoht/Sites/myapp/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError) ``

`Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.dylib`

`Reason: image not found - /Users/memoht/Sites/myapp/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle`

---

- Looked through [Postgres.app documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation)
- Upgrade from 9.2.2.0 to 9.2.4.1 isn't a new minor release so shouldn't involve pg_upgrade
- .bashrc has correct setting for PATH `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`
- Uninstalled, and reinstalled PG gem.
- Made the mistake of thinking I needed to install PostGIS via homebrew, but that automatically installed Postgres via Brew plus a slew of other dependencies.

If I swap out the Postgres.app version back down to 9.2.2.0 everything works again. Since Postgres.app is a drag and drop install, why has upgrading from 9.2.2.0 to 9.2.4.1 caused this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me and requires minimal hacking/configuring. You only need to do this once and it will work for every bundle install. Add the following to your .bash_profile, .bash_rc, or equivalent:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(Assuming you installed Postgres.app in the default location). Then restart your terminal session and try again.

Exporting to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH directly can cause serious problems with other apps that depend on it, but using the fallback path avoids these problems.

See also:

- [Error requiring pg under rvm with postgres.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453476/error-requiring-pg-under-rvm-with-postgres-app/16740568#16740568)
- https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/109#issuecomment-18387546

**EDIT**: It seems that setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH causes an error when you try to run psql. To fix this, you can add the following two lines to your .bash_profile:

```
alias psql="(. ~/.bash_profile; unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH; psql)";
```

This is assuming that you're using bash and that your .bash_profile is located in your home directory. If that's not the case (or if you're using a .bashrc or other environment setup instead of .bash_profile) change the `~/.bash_profile` part of the command to the path to your environment setup script.

The aliased commands basically start a subshell which does not effect your current bash environment. So when it unsets the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable, it's only temporary. After you exit psql the environment variable will be set again so that rails functions properly.

Comment: Hey now, I think you have just shed some light on my issue. I got so tangled up in my problem, I totally spaced checking the Github repo for this app. Thanks for the suggestion. I now see this problem is documented and hopefully they will get a fix in place. Thank you!

Comment: I think you may have trouble passing flags or piping to your psql command if aliased like this. Sometimes you want to do something like psql db < db.sql

Comment: Of course it's not a perfect solution. Just a workaround. From the issues page, it seems that downgrading Postgres.app also works.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your pg gem in your app was built against the old libraries. Try rebuilding it against the new Postgres.app:

```
$ gem uninstall pg
[...]
$ bundle install
[...]
"installing pg" (or something..)
```

Comment: I tried this already and it didn't work. I also made sure to clear my gem cache before reinstalling.

Comment: hrm, mentions `libssl` do you have openssl and friends installed?